# How to make local variable of a method of Superclass available to a subclass where the superclass is called by another class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

As you can see the code, I have a super class  `bar_for_foo_mixin()` and I have a subclass `myfoo(bar_for_foo_mixin):` I am computing a operation `self.Z = X+Y` in `bar()` method of superclass.

Now I want the self.z = 0 updated to the computation done in bar() method and inheirt this value to the subclass `myfoo(bar_for_foo_mixin):` and use it inside subclass.

```
class bar_for_foo_mixin():
    def __init__(self):
        self.z = 0

    def bar(self, q):
        x = 2
        y = 8
        self.z = x + y + q


class oldfoo():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    var = bar_for_foo_mixin()
    var.bar(10)


class myfoo(bar_for_foo_mixin):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myfoo, self).__init__()

    def hello(self):
        print("hello", self.z)


final = myfoo()
final.hello()
```

Result of the code:

```
hello 0
```

Expected result:

```
hello 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bar_for_foo_mixin` instance stored in your `oldfoo.var` class variable is a completely separate instance from the `myfoo` object you instantiated in the main program, so their instance variable `z` would not be shared.

If you would like a variable to be shared across all instances of a class, you should make it a class variable instead, and make methods that are dedicated to updating class variables, such as `bar_for_foo_mixin.bar`, a class method instead:

```
class bar_for_foo_mixin():
    z = 0

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls, q):
        x = 2
        y = 8
        cls.z = x + y + q


class oldfoo():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    var = bar_for_foo_mixin()
    var.bar(10)


class myfoo(bar_for_foo_mixin):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myfoo, self).__init__()

    def hello(self):
        print("hello", self.z)

final = myfoo()
final.hello()
```

This outputs:

```
hello 20
```

Comment: So I need to make it as a classmethod. Thanks @blhsing

Answer (score 1):

You're not even calling the `bar` method by the new `final` variable:

```
class bar_for_foo_mixin():
    def __init__(self):
        self.z = 0

    def bar(self, q):
        x = 2
        y = 8
        self.z = x + y + q

class myfoo(bar_for_foo_mixin):
    def __init__(self):
        super(myfoo, self).__init__()

    def hello(self):
        print("hello", self.z)

final = myfoo()
final.bar(10) # <== call it to take effect
final.hello() # ==> hello 20
```

Comment: I am new to this OOP, Is there a way that I can call the bar method in oldfoo(): class with argument 10 and compute the z and store it  to a variable and pass the stored value to subclass myfoo():

Comment: @VamsiNimmala Methods are called per object, the `z` attribute will be different for each instance, e.g.: creating instances `a = myfoo()`, `b = myfoo()` and `c = myfoo()`, then calling `bar` on each `a.bar(10); b.bar(20); c.bar(30)` (with different values), calling `hello` method then will show that they each have a different value for the `z` attribute: `a.hello(); b.hello(); c.hello()` results in `hello 20`, `hello 30` and `hello 40`.